# How to set the absolute position of the text field in an mx button?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I have a large mx button that I'm using and I'd like it to display my label across the whole button starting at around x=1 y=1. How do I accomplish this sort of absolute positioning?

Here is how it looks currently:

[image]

```
<mx:Button id="testButton" width="54" height="54" blendMode="layer" styleName="testStyle" label="D"/>

.testStyle
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    fontFamily: 'latha';
    fontWeight: bold;
    fontSharpness: 400;
    up-skin:        Embed("redSquare.png");
    over-skin:      Embed("redSquare.png");
    down-skin:      Embed("redSquare.png");
    disabled-skin:  Embed("redSquare.png");
    selected-over-skin:     Embed("redSquare.png");
    selected-up-skin:       Embed("redSquare.png");
    selected-down-skin:     Embed("redSquare.png");
    selected-disabled-skin: Embed("redSquare.png"); 
}
```

and I'm setting my font size dynamically:

```
testButton.setStyle("fontSize", 80*scale);
```

I understand that using an image and scaling that would probably be easier but this label needs to change frequently.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change the top/left padding styles :

```
testButton.setStyle("paddingTop", "-20");
testButton.setStyle("paddingLeft","-20");
```

Comment: I don't think that will mesh very well with my dynamic sizing and also doesn't resolve the label getting cut off.

Comment: Then you might need to create a custom component and place the label based and resize the button based on the labels size. You can read about creating custom components here : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=intro_3.html